# fopen() not creating a file nor writing to it (if i create the file manually)

Tags: php

first if all im sorry if i posted this in the wrong place but i really dont know where to ask this and especially that im not sure if the problem is of the code or something in my system

so i have a php7.3 server with apache2 running on kali linux 2019.4
and i wanted to make a simple fopen php app to write data entered from the user to the server so i enabled allow_url_fopen in the php.ini for both apache2 folder and the cli folder

this is my code

```
<html>
<style>
body{
background-color: black;
color: white;
}
.lli{
width: 80%;
}
</style>
<center>
<font color="white">
<br>
<br>
<form method="POST" href="VideoYeeter.php">
<br>
<input type="text" name="url" placeholder="Enter YouTube Video URL here">
<br><br>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
if (isset($submitted)) {
$file = fopen("/srv/htdocs/vid.ytdl" ,"w+") or die ("can't open file"); //this is my web folder (/srv/htdocs)
fopen($file,$_POST['url']);
fclose($file);
} else { ?>
<form method="POST" action="VideoYeeter.php">

<input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Download"></form>
<?php } // end of form ?><br><br>
<div><iframe src="vlog.php"></div>
</center>
</html>
```

the code runs as if there is no problem but when i go to see if the file was created i dont find anything

i tried chmod-ing everything to 777 and chown-ing everything to root i tried to output the file to another place accessible on the server (not /root/)

and yet it doesnt work
also if i create the file myself nothing gets written to it

so could i get some help please

Comment: You need to look more into webserver (Apache, Nginx) folder access rules. You cannot access your `root` folder, instead you can only access anything inside `www` folder (or the web folder).

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kali linux but any decent distro will have many security checks in place to avoid a webserver writing into sensitive directories. Can't you just store data elsewhere?

Comment: i said i tried storing it on my web folder (/srv/htdocs) as i said in "i tried to output the file to another place accessible on the server (not /root/)"

Comment: i'll edit it for more clearance

Comment: Is this the complete code? You only attempt to create the file if `$submitted` exists and you don't define it anywhere.

Comment: hmm .. this is the complete code but .. let me try the reliable if isset $_POST to see what happens

Comment: You cannot assign `fopen()` in `fopen($file,$_POST['url']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out im just as dumb as a spoon
im checking for an undefined variable which made the if statment false
so to fix it i just did

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){//code}
```

instead of

```
if(isset($submitted)){//code}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alvaro's answer $submitted might be the issue so what might be worth a try is to just do a simple test that does not rely on a variable being set to write to the file.

If it writes to the file then that proves the variable is the issue.  Failing that check your web server error logs to see what's happening there.